# Is there any way to organize pinned applications in the taskbar?

Tags: windows-10

I have a whole bunch of applications pinned on my Windows 10 taskbar (more than 10). These are items that I use on a daily basis, but not like everything running at the same time.

My problem is that at any time I am running 4-5 applications and there are 5-6 applications that are not running but pinned-up and occupying space. **It looks messy and disorganized.**

- I don't want to remove them from the taskbar because I would need quick access to them.
- However, I don't want those 5-6 apps to occupy the entire taskbar either because the taskbar gets filled up completely.

**Is there any way I could:**

a) Have pinned applications grouped under one square/category. But when I open the app then it appears as a separate entry?

b) Have all the pinned applications hidden in a region and expanded when I hover over that region?

Comment: regarding `a) Have pinned applications grouped under one square/category. But when I open the app then it appears as a separate entry?`: why don't use the start menu?

Comment: @Lenniey Because there are about 20 apps already pinned to the start menu too. I need to use those too almost regularly.